# How will I be able to join these 2 tables as the ID in the second table is embedded in JSON format?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, join

I will like to join these 2 tables base on the unique id but the unique id in one of the tables is embedded in JSON format.

1st table

```
unique_id | product_no | product
------------------------------
345644046 |         123|  acme widget
------------------------------
476897686 |         456|  acme gadget
```

2nd table

```
supplier_id | product_info | supplier_name
------------------------------
12345787871 |[{"Id":"345644046",...... }]|  john_wick
------------------------------
72736127172 |[{"Id":"476897686",...... }]|  justin_bieber
```

How will I be able to join these 2 tables as the ID in the second table is embedded in JSON format?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: @EdwardRadcliffe , thanks I have

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15, you'll want to `JSON_VALUE()` in the `JOIN` to extract the `Id` element.

Answer (score 0):

ProductInfo in table2 is a list of product right?

In this case, the clean solution is first to split the Table_2 in multiple rows

```
select * from Table_2
    cross apply OPENJSON(Table_2.product_info)
         WITH ( Id int)
```

this will give you

[image]

from there you have many ways to join with your table_1, ex:

```
select * from Table_1
left join (
    select * from Table_2
    cross apply OPENJSON(Table_2.product_info)
         WITH ( Id int)
     ) TmpTable on TmpTable.Id = Table_1.unique_id
```

Also there is another very ugly way to achieve this, just for fun

```
select * from Table_1
left join Table_2 on Table_2.product_info like CONCAT('%"Id":"', Table_1.unique_id , '%')
```